# rescaling the whole storyboard

Tags: ios

i have to edit an app that until now only ran on  an iphone 7.
Sadly the programmer didn't use constraints, but instead always set x,y,width and height of each view, label and so on. naturally, i f i run the app on my SE now, the app doesn't fit inside my screen. Since the storyboard is pretty full, i want to void having to go every single view in every Scene. Is there any way, that i can use a scaled version of it?

thanks in advance

Comment: If everything is done by code, you should replace the width parameter from fix px value to something like self.view.frame.size.width, but will again create problems at various other points, better to set the Constraints on storyboard and remove frames.

Comment: nope its done in the Storyboard

Comment: Time to roll up your sleeves and get coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any method of resizing "**bulk**" content in Storyboard.

My solution would be to create a function to get the `bounds` of each `UIView` and recalculating the new desired position/size based on the iPhone SE ratio - because just plain resizing down from **7** to **SE** would just make stuff stretched.

Comment: hmm i will try, but i will have to scale the labels too

Comment: Yeah, but just like @matt said, the sane solution would be just setting up all the _auto-layout constraints_.
But that's not the best solution for all cases, you've to measure what's your scenario and find a solution that scales up. If the UI is really complex and you've it "pixel perfect" on iPhone 7 - and clearly not with auto-layout - I would suggest to implement it 100% programatically - obviously if you have experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use autolayout constraints. That's what constraints *are* — they help you scale the interface. You have *lots* of iPhone sizes to deal with, from the 5s up to the XS Max; there is absolutely no way you can do that with manual frames.

Comment: Yes, but now you have charge of it, so now you need to do that. You cannot go forward with developing this app unless you use autolayout. The previous developer was just wrong. Do this the right way. That's what you're being paid for.